# Oracle ManagedDataAccess and special characters when logging in

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g, odp.net

I've encountered an issue with `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` which is that it seems to be impossible to use a non-ASCII connectionstring (non-ASCII is just an empirical guess).

This is all fine and dandy:

```
var cs = string.Format("Data Source={2};Password={1};User ID={0}", "user", "pwd", "mydb");
var connection = new OracleConnection(cs);
connection.Open();
```

But this does not work (å, ä and ö are swedish letters):

```
var cs = string.Format("Data Source={2};Password={1};User ID={0}", "åäö", "lösenord", "mydb");
var connection = new OracleConnection(cs);
connection.Open();
```

and throws

```
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Both users are capable of logging on via sqldeveloper.

Does anyone know of a way around this? Or is this a known limitation with the `ManagedDataAccess` (well, `DataAccess`) libraries from Oracle?

Ninja stuff, ie like using `Chr(int)`, is hard to do when signing in..

DB info:

```
NLS_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY   AMERICA
NLS_CURRENCY    $
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY    AMERICA
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  .,
NLS_CHARACTERSET    WE8MSWIN1252
NLS_CALENDAR    GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   AMERICAN
NLS_SORT    BINARY
NLS_TIME_FORMAT HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT  HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY   $
NLS_COMP    BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP FALSE
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
NLS_RDBMS_VERSION   11.2.0.1.0
```

EDIT:

Also tested this (ie adding quotes, as `OracleConnectionStringbuilder` does for "="):

```
var cs = string.Format("Data Source={2};Password={1};User ID={0}", "\"åäö\"", "\"lösenord\"", "mydb");
var connection = new OracleConnection(cs);
connection.Open();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem and this issue got fixed with the latest ODP Managed Driver version from September 16, 2016 (4.121.2.20150926).

Be careful to download it from the 32bit section of the Oracle website (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-087491.html) as Oracle seems to have missed to also add it to the 64 bit section, where the latest version is still from October 2015. For more information see also my question on the Oracle forums: https://community.oracle.com/message/14037653#14037653

Makes you kinda wonder though what Oracle is up to, since they did not support language specific characters for 3 years in their managed driver...

Comment: I'm not verifying this, but I believe you and mark it as correct (I no longer have access to Oracle databases :-P).

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with special characters (ex. "=") inside my username. I solved this problem with OracleConnectionStringBuilder. There must be some kind of encoding which it does. Try this, I hope it helps with your problem too.

```
OracleConnectionStringBuilder connBuilder = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder();
connBuilder.DataSource = "mydb";
connBuilder.UserID = "åäö";
connBuilder.Password = "lösenord";

var connection = new OracleConnection(connBuilder.ToString());
connection.Open();
```

Comment: Thx for the response. Seems to solve the issue for kinds of special characters. `OracleConnectionStringBuilder` does not escape åäö automatically apperently, but it doesn't work when I do it manually either. So no luck so far.

Comment: @ChristianAmado Haven't found a solution yet, we are forcing our users only to use ASCII-characters in passwords...

Comment: @flindeberg no solution on this.